# Execute arbitrary *real* code block (not a stringified version) in python

Tags: python

How can a random code block  be executed in python *without resorting to string-ifying it* . I am most likely *not* interested in using *eval* or *exec* .

So the use case would be to provide timing of a code block - but not requiring the hack of first converting the code block to a string:

```
def formatTimeDelta(td):
  return '%d.%d' %(td.total_seconds() , int(td.microseconds/1000))

def timeit(tag, block):
  def getNow(): return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime())

  startt = datetime.datetime.now()
  print('Starting %s at %s..' %(tag,getNow()))
  block  # Execute the code!
  duration = formatTimeDelta(datetime.datetime.now() - startt)
  print('Completed %s at %s with duration=%s secs' %(tag,getNow(), duration))
```

So then we would use something like:

Given a "random" code block

```
def waitsecs(nsecs):
   import time
   time.sleep(nsecs)
   print('I slept %d secs..' %nsecs)

timeit('wait five secs', (
   waitsecs(5)
))
```

I believe I had done all this in the past but can not seem to dig it up ..

Comment: I may be missing something, but this pretty much looks like what [`timeit.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) is for. For example `print(timeit.Timer(func_to_time).repeat(1, 1))`

Comment: The example i see is using strings .. `timeit.Timer('for i in xrange(10): oct(i)', 'gc.enable()').timeit()`  . If you see a usage with `Timer` that takes *real* code please do point it out.

Comment: `timeit.Timer` also accepts a callable, see my example

Comment: ah ok I see in source code the argument can be either a string or a callable. pls make an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`timeit.Timer`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer) does exactly that.

```
from time import sleep
from timeit import Timer

print(Timer(lambda: sleep(5)).repeat(1, 1))
# [5.000540999999999]
```

`repeat` is just one way to time the function, read the linked docs for other available methods.

Comment: I tried to understand from the source code `timeit.py` how the `Callable` were being handled but did not "get" it. If you were able to shed some light that would be a bonus.

Comment: `The stmt and setup parameters can also take objects that are callable without arguments` I probably read that once (or twice, ...) and immediately forgot it.

Comment: @javadba `timeit.Timer.__init__`  does a very explicit check: `elif callable(stmt):`

Comment: Yes I saw that but  I'm trying to go deeper and understand how the `stmt` / code block actually gets invoked . It should not be a `eval` or `exec` .. so what is the mechanism?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method I've found is using the [magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) `%timeit` in ipython or Jupyter notebook. You can specify the number of repetitions and loops if you want:

```
$ ipython                                                                                                           

In [1]: import time

In [2]: %timeit -n1 -r1 time.sleep(5)
5 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit [i**2 for i in range(10000)]
8.12 ms ± 14.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

You don't need any lambda, any defined function or any stringified code.

Comment: Thx -  I have mostly moved away from notebooks except for display purposes and do heavy lifting in `pycharm` . In any case will upvote as it does answer the question for notebook env's.

Answer (score 0):

Use a decorator, for example: 
@timeit decorator:

```
def timeit(method):
    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()
        if 'log_time' in kw:
            name = kw.get('log_name', method.__name__.upper())
            kw['log_time'][name] = int((te - ts) * 1000)
        else:
            print '%r  %2.2f ms' % \
                  (method.__name__, (te - ts) * 1000)
        return result
    return timed
```

Adding decorator to the method:

```
@timeit
def get_all_employee_details(**kwargs):
    print 'employee details'
```

Taken from: https://medium.com/pythonhive/python-decorator-to-measure-the-execution-time-of-methods-fa04cb6bb36d

Answer (score 0):

You can send callable to `timeit.timeit()` function, but **only** if it has no attributes. If it has any attributes, you should use setup-code.

`timeit.timeit()` function has [setup attribute](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit). You can send a code (but still stringified) to "eval" it before `timeit` `Timer` object starts to work. Here is the example:

```
import timeit

s = """
import math

def waka(number):
    return math.sqrt(number)
"""

timeit.timeit('waka(100)', setup=s)
```

It is how `timeit.timeit()` works:

> Create a Timer instance with the given statement, setup code and timer function and run its timeit() method with number executions. The optional globals argument specifies a namespace in which to execute the code.

Comment: point of the question was to avoid using strings for the code to be timed.